# How to calculate separable convolutions in the Xception paper?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I read the [Xception](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.02357.pdf) paper (there's even a [Keras Model](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/xception.py) for the describe NN) and it talks about separable convolutions.
I was trying to understand how **exactly** they are calculated. Rather than leaving it to imprecise words, I have included the piece of pseudo-code below that summarizes my understanding. The code maps from a feature map 18x18x728 to a 18x18x1024 one :

```
XSIZE = 18;
YSIZE = 18;
ZSIZE = 728;
ZSIXE2 = 1024;

float mapin[XSIZE][YSIZE][ZSIZE];  // Input map
float imap[XSIZE][YSIZE][ZSIZE2];  // Intermediate map
float mapout[XSIZE][YSIZE][ZSIZE2];  // Output map

float wz[ZSIZE][ZSIZE2]; // Weights for 1x1 convs
float wxy[3][3][ZSIZE2];  // Weights for 3x3 convs

// Apply 1x1 convs
for(y=0;y<YSIZE;y++)
  for(x=0;x<XSIZE;x++)
    for(o=0;o<ZSIZE2;o++){
      s=0.0;
      for(z=0;z<ZSIZE;z++)
        s+=mapin[x][y][z]*wz[z][o];
      imap[x][y][o]=s;
    }

// Apply 2D 3x3 convs
for(o=0;o<ZSIZE2;o++)
  for(y=0y<YSIZE;y++)
    for(x=0;x<XSIZE;x++){
      s=0.0;
      for(i=-1;i<2;i++)
        for(j=-1;j<2;j++)
          s+=imap[x+j][y+i][o]*wxy[j+1][i+1][o]; // This value is 0 if falls off the edge
      mapout[x][y][o]=s;
    }
```

Is this correct ? If not, can you suggest fixes similarly written in C or pseudo-C ?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found tf.nn.separable_conv2d in Tensorflow that does exactly this. So I built a very simple graph and, with the help of random numbers, I tried to get the code above to match the result. The correct code is :

```
XSIZE = 18;
YSIZE = 18;
ZSIZE = 728;
ZSIXE2 = 1024;

float mapin[XSIZE][YSIZE][ZSIZE];  // Input map
float imap[XSIZE][YSIZE][ZSIZE];  // Intermediate map
float mapout[XSIZE][YSIZE][ZSIZE2];  // Output map

float wxy[3][3][ZSIZE];  // Weights for 3x3 convs
float wz[ZSIZE][ZSIZE2]; // Weights for 1x1 convs


// Apply 2D 3x3 convs
for(o=0;o<ZSIZE;o++)
  for(y=0y<YSIZE;y++)
    for(x=0;x<XSIZE;x++){
      s=0.0;
      for(i=-1;i<2;i++)
        for(j=-1;j<2;j++)
          s+=mapin[x+j][y+i][o]*wxy[j+1][i+1][o]; // This value is 0 if falls off the edge
      imap[x][y][o]=s;
    }

// Apply 1x1 convs
for(y=0;y<YSIZE;y++)
  for(x=0;x<XSIZE;x++)
    for(o=0;o<ZSIZE2;o++){
      s=0.0;
      for(z=0;z<ZSIZE;z++)
        s+=imap[x][y][z]*wz[z][o];
      mapout[x][y][o]=s;
    }
```

The main difference is in the order that the two groups of convolutions are performed.
To my surprise, the order is important even when ZSIZE==ZSIZE2.